# How to apply group by function within pipe function so to not cause errors?

Tags: r

I want to make a plot using imdb_csv database. I want to see how along the years have changed the imdb_ratings for the animation movies, but I have a problem grouping the movies by year. I somehow managed to get group_by function to work but only if I started already new pipe in function. If I did a grouping by year in the pipe function where I had filtered some results ( in the first chunk) then I got an error that "Animation is not found". But the problem with the second chunk is that even though I applied select function I only get two columns, year and the average per year rating. Also the strange thing is that on the console the line `summarise(mean(as.numeric(imdbRating)))` always is shown below to any line I am executing.

Code:

```
imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>% filter(Animation == 1 & !str_detect(title, "\\\\$")) %>% 
                                 extract(title, c("title", "year"), 
                                         "^(.*?)(?:\\s*\\([^()]*?(\\d{4})[^()]*\\))?$")  


imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>% select(title, imdbRating, year) %>% 
                                 group_by(year) %>% 
                               mutate(n = n()) %>% 
                               summarise(mean(as.numeric(imdbRating)))
```

This is the result, that I get:

dput:

```
structure(list(year = c(1930, 1933, 1934, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 
1942, 1943, 1944, 1946, 1947, 1949, 1950, 1951), `mean(as.numeric(imdbRating))` = c(55, 
53, 58, 74, 67, 65.5, 74, 62.66667, 68.5, 63, 66.25, 65, 72, 
69.5, 71)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I don't understand why even though I selected title, imdbRating, it only shows summarise and year. Also how can I rename the summarise function?

Comment: You can just create a name `summarise(Mean = mean(as.numeric(imdbRating)))`

Comment: It is only showing two columns, because the first column is the 'grouping' column and the second is the summarised one (`summarise` only returns that column + any grouping column).  If you need more columns, either specify it in `group_by` or create a summarised output for that column.  Or else use `mutate` which would give all the columns after `select` and then do a `distinct`

Comment: Why do you want to rename the summarise function? Don't you like that name?

Answer (score 0):

You've selected the `title` but then you never do anything with it. If you want to keep the title in the results, then include that in the group_by function.

```
group_by(title, year) %>%
```

In fact, you don't need the initial select statement since the summarise function will only include the grouped columns and the summarised columns in the results, omitting every other column.

Regarding the total number `n`, once you've grouped by title and year, this will give you the number of ratings for animation movies for each title and for each year. If this is what you want, then include it in the summarise function, you don't need the mutate. So you can get by with just:

```
imdb_ratings <- imdb_ratings %>% group_by(title, year) %>%
    summarise(n=n(), Mean_rating = mean(as.numeric(imdbRating)))
```

A nice graphic would be a streamgraph:

[image]

If you don't want the title in the results (which I doubt because you went to a lot of trouble extracting it), then omit it in the group_by. The total number `n` will then be the total number of ratings for ALL animated movies per year and you won't have the title in the results (similar to the image you have shown).

Concerning the strange appearance on the console of `summarise(mean(as.numeric(imdbRating)))` below any line you execute... I guess you just need to manually delete it using the  button on the keyboard. (Ctrl + L won't clear it).